# nc, ncf options of newtx aren't working after MikTeX update

Tags: fonts, miktex, newtxmath, newtx

After the most recent MikTeX update (3/5/20) of newtx, the ncf option of newtxmath produces this [log file](https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=0D2D3A98C848F349&resid=D2D3A98C848F349%2113274&authkey=APXiMoOYPXLoN8o) indicating that OMLzncfmi.fd is missing.

A similar error occurs with the nc option, the missing file instead being OMLzncmi.fd. With no option selected, or with other font-compatibility options like libertine, newtxmath works fine. It seems these files are indeed missing from the newtx folder distributed by MikTeX, though I can't find them in the older version of newtx on CTAN either. This lead me to assume it was a file referencing problem in a .sty file in the MikTeX update, but the same error is produced with the version of newtx from CTAN. This is where I'm stuck, and would appreciate any insight into what's going wrong.

The source code that produced the log file is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[ncf]{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
    Hello
    \[\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: your screenshot is not the proper log-file but an interpretation of your editor. It is better to show the log. The fd-file was previously in the scholax package and the update seems to have lost it up. Write to the author of scholax/newtx.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question to include the log file and will email the package author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package author has fixed the issue, it was just a small error in the update.